# What is the Limit of IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, iis-6, scalability

What is the limit of IIS 6.0? like for example if i need to host 100,000 or 200,000 websites on IIS 6.0, how many machines would i need? or is IIS7 would be a better choice in this case for some reason?

Comment: this is a very vague question as it may depend on the server hardware specifications, network specifications and so on. You might want to further scope your question.

Comment: if the page you serve contains just <html></html>, i would say you can serve a bunch of sites...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above the scale isn't so much the number of websites you create in IIS, but how complex and how busy those sites are.

In IIS6 one website does not necessarily equate to one executing process on the server. Application pools can group multiple websites into a single executing process to group and/or isolate applications. Alternately a single app pool can spawn multiple executing processes to make better use of server hardware.

It might help if you were to provide more detail in your question about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  If you're going to be serving hundreds of thousands of sites it would probably be a good idea to partner with a hosting company, or get some assistance from someone who knows the ins and outs of IIS, or another platform in detail and has operational experience with working through large-scale hosting scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 is not radically different from IIS6 in any performance-related way; with one exception: you can run ASP.NET in a "native" pipeline mode that bypasses some processing steps. I prefer IIS7 (if I can choose) because of its manageability advantages. But like everyone else said here: the question is impossible to answer without more information.

Answer (score -4):

Hosting that many websites with IIS will be cost-prohibitive in licensing fees. Most large scale web hosting is done on Linux using Apache.